# Kentico - Change SearchResults Transformation to display Modified date instead of Created date

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I’m using Kentico v7.  I’m using the Smart Search Results widget and I’m using the built-in transformation to render the HTML (Document Types -> Root -> SmartSearchResults (ASCX type).  I noticed that transformation is using the “Created” date, but we would like to see the “Last Modified Date”.  I’ve looked into how to obtain the last modified date rather than the created date, and I see that it is quite involved.

I’ve evaluated the CMSModules\SmartSearch\Controls\SearchResults.ascx.cs control and have seen that it calls into a SearchHelper class and into a method of Search().  I was able to evaluate this method and see that the logic is quite complex in retrieving the data.

What approach can I do to change the date to “Last Modified” instead of the “Created” date?

(I realize this is a very specific Kentico question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding the following into a transformation

```
<%# GetSearchValue("DocumentModifiedWhen") %>
```

This can also be used to get other values of the searched document.